# Código switch problema al formularlo

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, vscode, switch

Me encuentro muy perdida con un ejercicio que tengo que resolver. Me pide lo siguiente: "El objetivo de este ejercicio es imprimir en pantalla un texto que estará condicionado de la siguiente manera. Utilizando switch deberemos evaluar si la variable "día" es lunes, miércoles o viernes; y, en ese caso, debe imprimir el texto "tenes clases". Para cualquier otro caso debe imprimir "no tenes clases".

Y el ejercicio viene con esto para empezar:

```
function tengoClases(dia) {
    switch (____) {
        //Escribe tu código aquí
    }
}
```

Intenté hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function tengoClases(dia) {
    switch (dia) {
    case 'lunes': 
    case 'miercoles':
    case 'viernes':
    console.log('tenes clases');
    break;
    default:
    console.log('no tenes clases');
    break;  
    }
}
```

y me tira error y la verdad es que intenté hasta agrupando los tres primeros casos y también me tira error. Ya no se qué más hacer

Comment: No se como lo estás depurando, pero tu código funciona bien. Puedes comprobarlo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/o8fc7v6h/  (expande la consola si ves que aparece minimizada en la parte inferior de las casillas de la derecha, donde pone **Console (beta)** para ver el resultado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola si aún no has podido encontrar la solución aquí está la mía espero sea de ayuda:

```js
function tengoClases(dia) {
    switch(dia) {
        case "lunes": return 'Tines clases';
            break;
        case "martes": return 'No tienes clases';
            break;
        case "miercoles": return 'Tines clases';
            break;
        case "jueves": return 'No tienes clases';
            break;
        case "viernes": return 'Tines clases';
            break;
        default:
            return 'No cumple con los parametros esperados';
            break;
    }  
}

let result = tengoClases('lunes');
console.log(result)
```

Espero te ayude y pues solo coloque uno algunos return dentro de cada case para que al ser utilizada la función está me retorne una respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda! Intenté con tu código y, lamentablemente, sigue tirando error :( De nuevo muchas gracias!

Comment: Pero el código funciona

Comment: @Delfi Haz una cosa, porque no tiene ningun sentido que TODO te de error cuando a nosotros no nos da ninguno. **Dinos que error te da**. Es más, si no sabes describirlo coges y capturas la pantalla con el error, y la pones en la pregunta para que nos demos cuenta de lo que tu consideras que es un error. Así veremos que herramienta te está diciendo que es un error.

Comment: @Delfi: Acabo de poner esta respuesta en un snippet para que la puedas ejecutar aquí mismo y veas que **no da error**. Se ejecuta bien.  **¿donde está tu error?**