# callbacks y funciones

Tags: javascript, vscode, callback, funcion

Debo trabajar con la siguiente consigna: "Vamos a crear tres funciones y ver cómo empezar a trabajar con callbacks.

La primera función se llamará doble. Esta recibirá un número y retornará el doble.

La segunda función se llamará triple. Esta recibirá un número y retornará el triple.

La tercera función se llamará aplicarCallback y recibirá por parámetro un numero y una función. Esta retornará el valor de aplicar dicha función al valor que recibió."

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
let numero1 = 2
function doble(numero1) {
    return (doble * numero1);
};

function triple(numero1){
    return (triple * numero1);
};

function aplicarCallBack(numero1, doble) {
    return aplicarCallBack;
};

aplicarCallBack(2, doble);
```

Me tiene realmente confundida ya que recién empiezo a ver este tema y no lo entiendo mucho, pero me gustaría y me serviría mucho la ayuda para ver qué estoy haciendo mal y corregir el error.
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: Corregir el error... ¿cuál error? Qué pasa cuando usas este código? :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! vos pasas una funcion, y devolves lo que devuelve esa funcion.. vos no sabes cual es la funcion.. tu callback, lo que hace, es llamar a la funcion que le dijeron que llame, con los parametros que le dijeron que use, y devuelve el resultado de eso...

Comment: No parece que hayas resuelto nada, las funciones que has puesto estan todas mal.  Llevas varias preguntas en este sitio y si bien has obtenido respuestas y has sido muy agradecida en los comentarios, en ninguna te has tomado la molestia de aceptar ninguna respuesta. Empieza conociendo el sitio, por favor, y sus normas básicas tanto para [ask] como para poner un [example], y léete [tour] para entender la dinámica. Y luego, ateniendote a eso, podrás formular buenas preguntas que gustosamente te ayudaremos a resolver.

Comment: @masterguru hola! recién me doy cuenta de que no le presté atención al tema de aceptar respuestas, pido mil disculpas. La consola donde estoy ejecutando el código me marca una serie de errores que no me entran en este comentario pero justamente necesitaría ayuda para ver cómo puedo resolverlo, por que hice exactamente(o al menos eso creo yo) lo que me pide la consigna del ejercicio y aún así está mal.

Comment: @Delfi ¿Esa consola es la misma que en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/562371/263200), cuando a todos nos daba que funcionaba bien, a ti te seguía dando error?  No se yo si me fiaría mucho de eso. Aún así, insisto en que el código de tu pregunta actual está todo mal. En cuanto a aceptar respuestas, tampoco se trata de aceptar por aceptar cualquiera de ellas, sino la que más te gustó o sirvió para tu pregunta, y así colaboras con la comunidad y ayudas a los demás que tengan la misma problemática que tu a encontrar lo que te fué más útil.

Comment: Volviendo a tu pregunta actual, empieza por las dos primeras funciones antes de ponerte con la del callback, y corrígelas.  Pista: Una funcion recibe puede recibir parámetros, en tu caso las dos primeras esperan solo uno, pero has puesto un "2" en una de ellas como parámetro que no significa nada. Un parámetro de una función es una variable que simboliza el dato pasado a la función, y que dentro de la función puede usarse sustituyendo al valor/dato pasado. Por otro lado, el método **return** puede devolver valores de la función ejecutada.

Comment: Fíjate que como **return** has puesto `return (doble);`  y  `return (triple);` que no significan nada tampoco, eso parece pseudocódigo y no javascript. Pregúntate a ti misma cómo calculas el doble de un número **matemáticamente** y eso es lo que debes poner en el **return**, usando el parámetro recibido como variable dentro de la función y multiplicándolo por la operación esperada (en caso del doble sería... y en el caso del triple sería...)... Corrige eso en tu pregunta y avanzaremos mucho y podremos ayudarte a resolver lo que te queda mucho mejor.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta las veces que sea necesario, no hace falta que la borres y crees una nueva, simplemente modifica la actual con los cambios descritos y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Esto te será de ayuda: https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/herramientas/javascript/funcion/ Saludos.

Comment: Las respuestas que acepté son las que me sirvieron! Acabo de editar la pregunta con otro código revisado, que no se si está bien, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @Delfi A ver, has mejorado, pero esto sigue no teniendo sentido: `return (doble * numero1);`  Fíjate en el enunciado que dice tan solo esto:  `La primera función se llamará doble. Esta recibirá un número y retornará el doble.` ... y no lo estás haciendo aún, pues has colocado la palabra **doble** como si eso fuera algo, que no lo es... Dicho de otro modo... ¿que número usas para calcular el doble de algo?  Pues eso es lo que debes poner en lugar de la palabra **doble** en el return.  Y con el triple más de lo mismo.  Sigue corrigiendo eso, pues hasta que no lo tengas no podemos seguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola amiga espero te encuentres bien, mira tome tu código y lo resolví de está forma.

```js
function doble(numero) {
    let resultado = numero * 2;
    return resultado;
};

function triple(numero){
  let resultado = numero * 3
    return resultado;
};

function aplicarCallBack(numero, funcion) {
    let resultado = funcion(numero);
    return resultado;
};

console.log(aplicarCallBack(2, doble))
console.log(aplicarCallBack(2, triple))
```

Te explicare la primera función lo que toma es un valor x desde sus parámetros y dentro del cuerpo de la función hace un cálculo el cual el numero ingresado se multiplica por dos, la segunda función es básicamente lo mismo y ya por ultimo tenemos nuestra última función la cual hace el llamado de callback a otra función y básicamente está recibe dos parámetros los cuales son un número x y una función, puede ser cualquiera de las creadas anteriormente, dentro del cuerpo de la función lo que se realizo fue la creación de una variable la cual contendrá el resultado de la función y aquí usamos la función que pasamos como parámetro y dentro de ella le colocaremos el número que también recibe como parámetro realiza su respectiva función y la retorna, ya por ultimo imprimimos por consola y usamos nuestra última función y a está le pasamos dos datos los cuales son un número x y alguna de nuestras anteriores funciones y eso es todo

ya por ultimo te recomiendo visitar está página aquí encuentras documentación de lo que sea para JavaScript
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

espero sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de ponerlo en un snippet para que lo pueda ejecutar y entender mejor con la práctica, agregando tambien un callback a **triple**.

Comment: Hola, amigo me podrías explicar cómo colocar esos snippet  ?

Comment: Lo tienes en el editor, pulsando el botón que se parece a esto: `<>` (después del botón de imagen) en la barra superior del editor (allí lo llaman **fragmentos**).

Comment: Vale gracias amigo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @JuanSebastianAriasRobayo ! Yo estoy trabajando con estos ejercicios en una consola que pertenece a una página llamada playground que tiene su propio editor de texto y consola, y aunque este código que me pasaste se ejecuta lo más bien en VSC, en la consola de PG me tira error :( aún así, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @Delfi Al fin nos has dicho el sitio que estás usando!  Acabo de probarlo y a mi no me da error si escojo una plantilla javascript vacia (**Empty Javascript**) y pego el código de esta respuesta tal cual.  No se como lo estás haciendo tu, pero algo haces mal y de ahí los errores que siempre tienes y que no somos capaces de ver.

Comment: Perdón, no soltaba el dato por que no sabía si iban a poder entenderme jajaja por que asumí que es algo que no usa todo el mundo. El tema con esa consola es que, donde yo la uso no puedo cambiarle la plantilla, trae una predeterminada que nisiquiera sé cual es :(

Comment: Si sales de la página y vuelves a entrar (o abre una pestaña nueva) y le das al botón de **Get Started** te permite escoger varias plantillas de diversos lenguages... tu debes escoger la de **Empty Javascript** para probar tu código y las respuestas que te demos... las otras ni idea, no las uses si no sabes lo que son

Comment: a menos que estés siguiendo algún tipo de curso alli mismo, cosa que desconozco, pero si es solo para probar javascript a pelo usa la plantilla vacia de javascript

Comment: @masterguru Sí, ese es el tema, estoy haciendo un curso y tengo que usar sí o sí esa consola :/ mil gracias por toda la ayuda, en serio!

Comment: @Delfi mmm... pero el curso es de playground?  no veo que hagan cursos... o no se verlo... Si el curso es de otro sitio entonces deberías usar la plantilla vacia de javascript para probar tu código (y nuestras respuestas).  Si nos dices que curso es que te obligan a usar esa web te podremos ayudar mejor (hoy yo ya no, me toca dormir... suerte!)

Comment: Nono, el curso no es de playground, es de un lugar llamado Digital House, y ellos usan la consola PlaygroundCode para que los alumnos practiquen haciendo ejercicios. Gracias por todo!

Comment: @Delfi Pues aún me das más la razón en que debes usar la plantilla que pone **Empty Javascript** (es este [enlace directo](https://playcode.io/empty_javascript))  cuando entres al playground (que por cierto, en google me manda aquí:  `https://playcode.io`  y entiendo que estamos hablando del mismo sitio).  Dudo que los del curso te hayan dicho que uses otra cosa y lo deben dar por sobreentendido.

Comment: @masterguru Al final, con ayuda de una compañera pude hacer que me tome el código en la consola. De nuevo, te agradezco muchísimo y voy a tomar tu ayuda para próximos ejercicios y errores. Gracias!

Comment: De nada! Suerte! :-) Realmente me tenias preocupado pues por lo que me parece estás empezando a programar y si usas mal las herramientas te puede generar demasiada fustración para continuar con ello, cuando no es tan difícil si aprendes bien como depurar tu código (en javascript básicamente es usando la consola) y tienes la suficiente paciencia y tesón en solucionar los errores. Saludos!