# Reemplazo array en función

Tags: javascript, array, visual-studio, funciones, replace

En mi curso de programación, me piden hacer el siguiente ejercicio: "Nuestra misión, ahora, es crear una función llamada reemplazoFastFast que va a recibir los siguientes tres parámetros:

1. Un texto.
2. La palabra que vamos a buscar para reemplazar.
3. La palabra que vamos a usar para reemplazar.

La función deberá devolver el texto con la palabra reemplazada."

- Es importante aclarar que debo usar el método de array .replace
  Yo lo resolví de la siguiente manera y en la consola que uso(PlaygroundCode)me tira error, o sea no me lo acepta como que está bien:

```
function reemplazoFastFast('Hola ,¿cómo estás?', 'estás','están'){
    return ('Hola,¿cómo están?')
}
console.log(reemplazoFastFast);
```

Sé que no está bien, pero a la vez no entiendo como meter el replace dentro de la función y estoy muy frustrada por que no me sale y ya lo intenté resolver de otras formas que me tiraron error también. Cualquier ayuda, se agradece!

Comment: En la funciones se declaran parámetros, no asignas directamente su valor a menos que sean valores por defecto y no se declaran de esa manera. En el console.log no estás llamando a la función con los argumentos necesarios

Comment: @GmrYael Hola! Voy a tomar los tips que me das y voy a volver a codearlo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un array no tiene método replace, un string lo tiene

Comment: Lecturas recomendadas: [Declaración de función](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#declaraci%C3%B3n_de_funci%C3%B3n) y [Llamar funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#llamar_funciones).  Con que tan solo te leas los primeros párrafos de esos enlaces deberías entender lo mínimo sobre las funciones y espero te ayude a comprender lo que estás haciendo mal en tu pregunta. Suerte!

Comment: Una vez entiendas lo que es una función necesitarás utilizar algún método de búsqueda en cadenas (hay varios, entre ellos el más común sería [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) creo yo) para usarlo en un condicional [if](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), y si se cumple esa búsqueda puedes usar el método [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para sustituir la cadena de texto buscada por la de reemplazo.

Comment: No te sulfures con todo lo que no comprendas de esos enlaces. Tu a lo tuyo y mira de comprender lo mínimo necesario para usarlos, que el resto ya lo irás cogiendo con el tiempo.  Aprender a programar también se basa en prueba y error, por lo tanto no te de miedo copiar los ejemplos que veas por ahí, ponerlos en el playground, ejecutarlos, y si entiendes lo que hacen coges y los modificas para tu caso en concreto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como te mencionan en los comentarios, no puedes asignar directamente los valores a la función, esta función debería recibir 3 parámetros:

```
function reemplazoFastFast(texto,buscar,reemplazar){ }

console.log(reemplazoFastFast("Hola ,¿cómo estás?", "estás", "están"));
```

Ahora para reemplazar, tendrías que usar el método `replace()` y recibir como parámetro a `buscar` y `reemplazar`:

```
texto.replace(buscar,reemplazar)
```

En donde:

```
// texto: es la cadena. => "Hola ,¿cómo estás?"
// buscar: es la palabra que buscará en la cadena. => "estás"
// reemplazar: es la palabra que queremos reemplazar a lo buscado. => "están"
```

Tu código sería el siguiente:

```js
function reemplazoFastFast(texto,buscar,reemplazar){
  return texto.replace(buscar,reemplazar);
}

console.log(reemplazoFastFast("Hola ,¿cómo estás?", "estás", "están"));
```

> ***Enlaces:** **[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)***

Comment: Quizá prefieras [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) para reemplazar todas las ocurrencias.

Comment: Claro, también sería otra opción...

Comment: Si bien la respuesta soluciona la pregunta, y considero que es aceptable por la comunidad, me hubiera gustado que lo hubiera probado primero ella y que tuviera más dudas a solucionar intentando usar las funciones antes de dársela (a nivel personal, ojo, no me estoy quejando de ti, pero el OP ya estuvo practicando con funciones en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/563000/callbacks-y-funciones) y por lo que veo aún no las ha entendido por su cuenta).  Aun así, me doy por satisfecho si esta vez entiende bien la respuesta, gracias.

Comment: Claro, entiendo eso, es por ello que traté de explicar lo más detallado posible, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Sí, sí, tu explicación es más que suficiente, y de ahí mi voto :-)  (pero como ya conozco al OP de esa otra pregunta, y aún cojea con cosas básicas, quería ver si lo conseguía esta vez por su cuenta... ya te digo, es algo más personal en esta ocasión y para que no termine copiando y pegando para salir del paso y repita una pregunta similar en el futuro). De nuevo, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: No creo que el OP copie y pegue el código omitiéndose los detalles... pero bueno, esto ya vendría ser decisión del OP, aprender o solo saltarse el paso fácil, no por nada los detalles y la documentación están ahí...  y sí, tienes razón, la mejor forma de aprender es **intentándolo** =) saludos.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Hola! Te agradezco muchísimo por toda la explicación, en serio. De hecho con tu explicación lo pude entender muchísimo mejor haciendo toda la lógica necesaria.

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarle, saludos.

Comment: @masterguru Hola! Quería responder un par de cosas sobre los comentarios que dejaste. 1.- es cierto que todavía me cuesta mucho entender lo de funciones, de hecho lo entiendo más que nada a nivel muy básico, y si tengo que meter otros temas me cuesta el doble. 2.- No te preocupes que no pego y copio las soluciones que me dan! Intento ver paso por paso cada parte del código y veo como se hizo. Y último pero no menos importante, siempre que vengo acá a dejar mis dudas, es por que antes leí otras páginas, intenté hacerlo muchas veces el ejercicio de maneras diferentes y nada fue de ayuda +

Comment: @masterguru de hecho me cuesta entender los ejemplos que ponen sobre ciertos temas en otras páginas por que los ejemplos están hechos con temas que todavía no entiendo por que no me enseñaron, entonces me cuesta el doble, me mareo y no entiendo. Por ejemplo, los links de Mozilla, tienen ejemplos sobre los temas con los que tuve dudas, pero esos ejemplos no son básicos, son más bien un poco avanzados, o al menos así lo siento yo que recién empiezo con todo esto, y no logro entender lo que necesito. Aún así, te agradezco muchísimo por siempre ayudarme y mandarme links! Juro que los leo todos +

Comment: @masterguru y muchos de ellos me sirvieron para hacer estos ejercicios!

Comment: @Delfi Te creo, no dudo de tu buena intención en aprenderlo todo y no simplemetne copiar y pegar :-) Pero al igual que tu, recuerdo que cuando empecé a programar tuve miles de dudas y en muchos casos desistí de entenderlo en ese momento porque me apremiaba más obtener resultados que aprender el porque funcionaban (eran ya casos practicos que necesitaba resolver).  En tu caso estas aprendiendo a programar y es importante que te pares a intentar entender todas las respuestas que te han dado, asi como los comentarios. Y cuesta, y mucho, hacerlo al empezar.

Comment: @Delfi Y de ahí que me enrolle tanto contigo. Bueno, me enrollo mucho siempre, pero especialmente con los casos como los tuyos aun más para intentar ayudar a superar esos primeros pasos, pues son decisivos para el que pregunta pues puede salir fustrado y pensar que la programación no es para el, o reforzado y motivado.  En mis comentarios no acostumbro a dar el pez (sino daría una respuesta), sino la caña, y creo que a veces disgusto a algunos, pero no es mi intención ni mucho menos, y si veo que eso ocurre pido las correspondientes disculpas :-)  Te animo a continuar aprendiendo, Saludos!

Comment: @masterguru No te preocupes! Yo no me lo tomé a mal, simplemente sentí la necesidad de dar mis explicaciones para que no piensen algo que no es. De nuevo, gracias por todo!